# Use a list created in another class in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
QComboBox, QCompleter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel, QStringListModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import pandas as pd
import pickle

class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.setEditable(True)

    # add a filter model to filter matching items
    self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

    # add a completer, which uses the filter model
    self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
    # always show all (filtered) completions
    self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
    self.setCompleter(self.completer)

    # connect signals
    self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
    self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


# on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox 
def on_completer_activated(self, text):
    if text:
        index = self.findText(text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))


# on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well 
def setModel(self, model):
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
    self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
    self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


# on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
def setModelColumn(self, column):
    self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
    self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
    super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column) 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):


    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tennis Form')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/Tennis-icon.png'))   

    button1 = QPushButton("ATP", self)
    button1.resize(350,50)
    button1.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod1)
    button1.move(225, 200)   

    button2 = QPushButton("WTA", self)
    button2.resize(350,50)
    button2.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod2)
    button2.move(225, 275)

    self.select = Select_player(self)

def clickMethod1(self):
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    df = pd.read_pickle('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/ATP_Rankings.pickle')
    my_list = df["Name"].tolist()
    self.select.show()

def clickMethod2(self):
    import pandas as pd
    import pickle
    df = pd.read_pickle('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/WTA_Rankings.pickle')
    my_list = df["Name"].tolist()
    self.select.show()

class Select_player(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Select_player,self).__init__()       
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Select Players')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Project-Tennis/Tennis-icon.png'))

    self.player1 = ExtendedComboBox(self)
    self.player1.resize(350,25)
    self.player1.move(225, 200)

    self.player2 = ExtendedComboBox(self)
    self.player2.resize(350,25)
    self.player2.move(225, 275)

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I created a main window (MainWindow) on which there are two buttons which both create a list as "my_list" when pushed. The list values are different depending on the button pushed.

In the next window (Select_player) that opens when one of the button is pushed, there are two Combo boxes.

What I want to achieve is to have the values in "my_list" which were previously created in the main window into the two combo boxes.

I have tried something like self.player1.addItems(my_list) but I get the error "name 'my_list' is not defined".

How can I use "my_list" created in the class MainWindow in Select_player?

Comment: Make `my_list` an instance attibute: `self.my_list = df["Name"].tolist()`. Then you can get it in your other code with `mainWin.my_list`. BTW, don't put `import` statements inside methods, put them up the top of the script, where they belong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the method but I get the error "name 'mainWin' is not defined" when I try to add the items. What might be causing that error message?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access `mainWin` before it exists. Sorry, I don't know PyQt, so I can't give more specific advice.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try to find what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

my_list has local scope in the functions in which you defined it (clickMethod1() and clickMethod2()).  my_list is not visible outside those functions.

You could declare my_list as an attribute of the MainWindow class - then you can access it as mainWin.my_list.

Comment: Thank you. But when I try to add the items I get the error: "name 'mainWin' is not defined".